# How to exploit this piece of code? (format string in printf?)

Tags: c, programming, directory-traversal, format-string

So this piece of code is vulnerable to format string vuln (I think) in the `printf()` function. It reads a file in `/tmp/file` so I've tried writing different modifier/strings in that file and see what happens but I got nothing interesting. When I write few lines containing `%x %x %x %x %s` I can see that sometimes the line break is not there and I get a line actually containing 2 lines.

I can also insert a `\0` at the beginning of the line for example if I do `\0 AAA` and the same thing for `b` and `c` and then copy/paste this a few time the result is:

```
\0 AAAA
\0 bbbbb
\0cccccc\0 AAAA
```

The exploitation goal is to read some file in a protected directory but I have no idea how I would do that using this vulnerability.
Any tips is welcome, thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int arc, char **argv)
{

    int fd;
    fd = open("/tmp/file",O_RDONLY);

    if (fd < 0)
    {
        printf("Cannot open file\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    int nb_lus;
    char line[20];
    while ((nb_lus = read(fd,line,20)) > 0)
    {
        line[nb_lus-1] = '\0';
        printf("%s",line);
    }

    close(fd);
    system("/bin/rm /tmp/file");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31834/discussion-on-question-by-user3916237-how-to-exploit-this-piece-of-code-format).

Comment: Please give information about the security challenge where this is from.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you control the input file `/tmp/file` and this piece of program is run with privileges to read a protected file. Your goal is to read the protected file.

I failed to see any issue in this code. The format string is not controlled by the input and the missing line feeds you saw was because the last char of every 20 bytes is being replaced with a `\0` (which stops `printf` from reading beyond the buffer).

However, as @MikeOunsworth suggested, all you have to do is to make `/tmp/file` a symlink to the protected file and you'll get the contents (with every 20th byte replaced, of course).